# When I click on a button, I want to show an element only if another element contains a specific text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hide, display

So as an example, when I click on the button (class="button"), it will show class="test2" if class="test1" contains the text "Select".

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="Button"></input>
<div class="test1">Select</div>
<div class="test2">12345</></div>
```

Comment: Show your attempts

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="test1">Select</div>
<div class="test2" hidden>12345</div>
<div class="test1">Select</div>
<div class="test2" hidden>54321</div>
<div class="test1">hide</div>
<div class="test2" hidden>67890</div>
<input class="button" type="button" value="Button"></input>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.button').on('click',function(){
        $.each($('.test1'), function(key, value){
        var tdValue = $(value).text();
            console.log(value, key);
        if (tdValue == 'Select'){
            $(value).next('.test2').show();
            $(value).hide();
        }else{
            $(value).next('.test2').hide();
            $(value).hide();
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is for multiple value to show.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="test1">Select</div>
<div class="test2" hidden>12345</div>
<input class="button" type="button" value="Button"></input>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$('.button').on('click',function(){

    var tdValue = $('.test1').text();
    if (tdValue === 'Select'){
        $('.test2').show();
        $('.test1').hide();
    }else{
        $('.test2').hide();
        $('.test1').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: please add explanation of how your code solves the problam

Comment: as your question when you click on class button it will show class test2 value if class test1 text is select2 only....that's the solution for the case if you won't multiple value to hide or show so you have to use .cach function of j-query ok.